# boost::asio::io_service synchronization by strand crashed

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety, boost-asio

I'm trying to use boost asio and io_service to run my tasks.

I produced the code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void work(boost::asio::io_service::strand& sync);
void sentCompleted(boost::asio::io_service::strand& sync);
void mySend(boost::asio::io_service::strand& sync);

void work(boost::asio::io_service::strand& sync)
{
    std::cout << "id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", work()" << std::endl;

    mySend(sync);
    sync.post(sync.wrap(std::bind(&work, std::ref(sync))));
}

void sentCompleted(boost::asio::io_service::strand& sync)
{
    std::cout << "id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", sentCompleted()" << std::endl;
}

void mySend(boost::asio::io_service::strand& sync)
{
    std::cout << "id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", mySend()" << std::endl;

    sync.post(sync.wrap(std::bind(&sentCompleted, std::ref(sync))));
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::io_service::strand sync(ioService);
    sync.post(sync.wrap(std::bind(&work, std::ref(sync))));

    std::vector<std::thread*> threads;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(new std::thread(std::bind(static_cast<size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(&boost::asio::io_service::run), &ioService)));
    }

    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread* thread) { thread->join(); });

    return 0;
}
```

but program is crashing with output:

> id: 140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() id:
>   140320651073280, sentCompleted() id: 140320676251392, work() id:
>   140320676251392, mySend() id: 140320651073280, sentCompleted() id:
>   140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() id:
>   140320651073280, sentCompleted() id: 140320676251392, work() id:
>   140320676251392, mySend() id: 140320651073280, sentCompleted() id:
>   140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() id:
>   140320651073280, sentCompleted() id: 140320676251392, work() id:
>   140320676251392, mySend() id: 140320651073280, sentCompleted() id:
>   140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() id:
>   140320651073280, sentCompleted() id: 140320676251392, work() id:
>   140320676251392, mySend() id: 140320651073280, sentCompleted() id:
>   140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() id:
>   140320651073280, sentCompleted() id: 140320676251392, work() id:
>   140320676251392, mySend() id: 140320651073280, sentCompleted() id:
>   140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() id:
>   140320651073280, sentCompleted() id: 140320676251392, work() id:
>   140320676251392, mySend() id: 140320651073280, sentCompleted() id:
>   140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() id:
>   140320651073280, sentCompleted() id: 140320676251392, work() id:
>   140320676251392, mySend() id: 140320651073280, sentCompleted() id:
>   140320676251392, work() id: 140320676251392, mySend() Aborted (core
>   dumped)

Thought that I'm using strand incorrectly, so I tried to synchronize io_service::run handlers by recursive_mutex, and also situation is the same...

Code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

class Sender
{
public:
    Sender(boost::asio::io_service& ioService):
        ioService_(ioService) {}

    void work()
    {
        sync_.lock();
        std::cout << "id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", work()" << std::endl;
        mySend();
        sync_.unlock();

        ioService_.post(std::bind(&Sender::work, this));
    }

    void mySend()
    {
        std::cout << "id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", mySend()" << std::endl;
        ioService_.post(std::bind(&Sender::sentCompleted, this));
    }

    void sentCompleted()
    {
        sync_.lock();
        std::cout << "id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", sentCompleted()" << std::endl;
        sync_.unlock();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service &ioService_;
    std::recursive_mutex sync_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;

    Sender sender(ioService);
    sender.work();

    std::vector<std::thread*> threads;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(new std::thread(std::bind(static_cast<size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(&boost::asio::io_service::run), &ioService)));
    }

    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread* thread) { thread->join(); });

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
id: 140231283394336, work() id: 140231283394336, mySend() id:
140231283390208, sentCompleted() id: 140231283390208, work() id:
140231283390208, mySend() id: 140231283390208, work() id:
140231283390208, mySend() id: 140231151974144, sentCompleted() id:
140231283390208, work() id: 140231283390208, mySend() id:
140231283390208, sentCompleted() id: 140231283390208, work() id:
140231283390208, mySend() id: 140231283390208, sentCompleted() id:
140231283390208, work() id: 140231283390208, mySend() id:
140231283390208, sentCompleted() id: 140231283390208, work() id:
140231283390208, mySend() id: 140231151974144, sentCompleted() id:
140231283390208, work() id: 140231283390208, mySend() id:
140231151974144, sentCompleted() id: 140231151974144, sentCompleted()
id: 140231283390208, work() id: 140231283390208, mySend() id:
140231151974144, sentCompleted() Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance! Best regards.

Comment: What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: Also, how did you compile and link the program?

Comment: In future I will add some data modification to mySend() and sentComplete(). I want to block other threads when mySend() and sentCompleted() is called. Command for link and compile: clang++ -std=c++11 -lboost_system -pthread kopa.cpp

Comment: Your platform may require `-lboost_system-mt` for multi-threaded code.

Comment: Wait, the output shows no linebreaks. Why is that? What platform do you use?